# Threats for video files

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

I'm trying to figure out what are the known vulnerabilities in video file formats? 
And, if by any chance, anyone knows about an application to scan or whitelist these files from any harmful countenance?

Answer (score 3):

Vulnerabilities will be in the software which process a particular file format.

Example: firefox's PDF viewer having a bug while processing a particular pdf format file.

The crafted or malicious data in that pdf file may lead to crash of the software, which may further lead to privilege escalation and getting hold on the system.